# Yii2 send email with template problems

Tags: email, swiftmailer, yii2-basic-app

Hello I have problem  with email creation.
 the footer is duplicated:

```
<div class="footer">With kind regards, <?= Yii::$app->name ?> team</div>
Printing two times the same text
```

My settings in web.app:

```
   'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@app/mail/',
        'useFileTransport' => false,//set this property to false to send mails to real email addresses
        //comment the following array to send mail using php's mail function
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'mypassword',
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
        ],
    ],
```

And how I send email:

```
$content='test text';
    \Yii::$app->mailer->compose('@app/mail/layouts/html',        ['content'=>$content])
        ->setFrom('myemail@gmail.com')
        ->setTo('emailto@gmail.com')
        ->setSubject('test')
        ->send();
```

Comment: I try to create second file in mail/templates/templ.php but  when I send email  it write two templates : layout/html and templates/templ : **`\Yii::$app->mailer->compose('@app/mail/templates/templ',['content'=>$content])`**